# Execute code for each occurance of a word in a string

Tags: php, string, function, foreach, explode

I have the following string...

```
HEADER*RECIPIENT MAIN *FOOTER
```

I want to know how to use PHP to loop through this string and execute a function on every occurrence of the word HEADER*, *FOOTER, MAIN and RECIPIENT.

I tried this myself using a basic for-each loop after exploding the string but I find that it groups all the elements together.

I need it to follow the order in which they are found. My method works with one page only.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you post the code you have tried? This is how things work here on StackOverflow.

Comment: What code do you want to execute? What do you want it to do? Will it modify the string? Will the text you are searching for always be the same?

Comment: as a first hint: look at the preg_replace_callback() function. You can use a dummy function if you don't want to really replace the content but just execute other code.

Comment: $headers = explode("HEADER*", $theheaders);  
  foreach ($headers as $header) {
   theheader($form); 
  }
  
  $recipients = explode("RECIPIENT", $therecipients);
  
  foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
   recipient($form, $custtitle, $custfname, $custsname, $address1, $address2, $address3, $address4, $postcode, $custno);
  }  
  $mains = explode("MAIN", $themains);
  
  
  foreach ($mains as $main) {
   main($form, $custtitle, $custsname, $accidentdate, $username);
  }
  $footers = explode("*FOOTER", $thefooters); 
  
  foreach ($footers as $footer) {
   thefooter($form, $custno); 
  }

Comment: Sorry for the mess!Don't know how to reply properly on here

Comment: Basically I need to use the string as a reference to construct a letter so for each page it needs to run a header main and footer function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i was doing a simple template parser, in one old framework i developed years ago, using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

Basically, you provide your templateParser the source template and you handle the token occurrences inside your callback function. This is a skeleton, obviously you should make your custom implementation of it, and design your regex to match tokens like HEADER*, *FOOTER, etc.

```
<?php
    /**
     *  @param string $tpl
     *    The template source, as a string.
     */
    function templateParser($tpl) {
      $tokenRegex = "/your_token_regex/";
      $tpl = preg_replace_callback($tokenRegex , 'template_callback', $tpl);
      return $tpl;
    }

    function template_callback($matches) {
      $element = $matches[0];
      // Element is the matched token inside your template
      if (function_exists($element)) {
        return $element();
      } else if ($element == 'HEADER*') {
        return your_header_handler();
      } else {
        throw new Exception('Token handler not found.');
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I've tried to get this working using the regex      /(\bHEADER\b)/   I just get the following errors...  PHP Warning: function_exists() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given  PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Token handler not found.'  nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: template_callback(Array)\n#1   preg_replace_callback('/(\\bHEADER\\b)/', 'template_callba...', 'HEADER*RECIPIEN...')\n#2   templateParser('HEADER*RECIPIEN...')\n#3 {main}\n thrown  not sure why I'm getting the errors nor am i sure about the regex at all

Comment: The template_callback function works perfectly once I get rid of the first if condition as my function is called the header and not header but nonetheless this is what I need so thanks @brazorf :)